# Sitecore reports - How to add a filter (DMS v6.5)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

Need to figureout a way to add a new filter to my report. How can I do this in DMS.

I can create a filter with Analytics, but in the report definition item there is no way to link that filter to report.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha!

[Here is the solution...](http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/adding-site-filters-to-dms-reports-with-sitecore-6-5/)

Comment: The reference-only answers don't bring the same amount of value as the full answer does. Consider modifying your answer to contain an excerpt of the referenced blog post. In this case, if the target blog goes offline, the current answer won't be helpful.